# Is there a builtin way to define a function that takes either 1 argument or 3?

Tags: python, function

There's this error in Python when calling builtin `type()` with no arguments:

```
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

How can we define such a method?
Is there a builtin way? Or we need to do something like this:

```
>>> def one_or_three(*args):
...   if len(args) not in [1,3]:
...     raise TypeError("one_or_three() takes 1 or 3 arguments")
... 
>>> one_or_three(1)
>>> one_or_three()
TypeError: one_or_three() takes 1 or 3 arguments
>>> one_or_three(1,2)
TypeError: one_or_three() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

Comment: I can't think of an in-built way.. a couple of alternatives are using a decorator or an `assert`.

Comment: This *specific* error is hardcoded in `typeobject.c` in the function `type_new`. It returns a valid result for `nargs == 1` and then throws an error for `if (nargs != 3)`. Alas, peeking at the source doesn't readily tell if it can be done in native Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, type is not native Python (at least in CPython), but C.

The `inspect` module can confirm it easily (even if documented as a builtin function, `type` is implemented as a class in CPython):

```
>>> print(inspect.signature(type.__init__))
(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
>>> print(sig.parameters['self'].kind)
POSITIONAL_ONLY
```

The parameter kind is `POSITIONAL_ONLY`, which cannot be created in Python.

That means that it will not be possible to reproduce **exactly** the behaviour of type.

Python source allows only 2 signatures for variable number of arguments:

- 3 parameters, 2 of them being optional:

  ```
  type(object_or_name, bases = None, dict = None)
  ```

  This would be very different, because it will accept gladly `type(obj, None)` which is definitely not what is expected here
- a simple `*args` parameter whose length will be tested *by hand* - your proposal. This will be much closer to native `type` behaviour, because it really requires 1 or 3 parameters, whatever the values.

TL/DR: the answer to your question is that we really need the *something like that* way.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is perfectly possible in Python.

```
def one_or_three(one, two=object(), three=object()):
    two_sentinel, three_sentinel = one_or_three.__defaults__
    if (two == two_sentinel) != (three == three_sentinel):
        raise TypeError("one_or_three() takes 1 or 3 arguments")
    ...
```

This has the benefits of named arguments (semantic value, passing in by name, etc) but is basically a variation on checking the values of some variables to know whether one or three things were passed.

Note that the two calls to `object()` produce two different objects and bind them to the function:

```
>>> one_or_three.__defaults__
(<object object at 0x00168540>, <object object at 0x00168ED0>)
```

This way, they are globally unique. If you instead used `None` as your sentinel object, then it wouldn't be possible to pass in `None` as an argument (though of course that may be desired).